# Assign result of block to a variable (gives SyntaxError)

Tags: javascript

If I open a Node REPL, and enter this code, I can see that it evaluates to 3:

```
$ node
> { let a = 1 + 2; a }
3
>
```

However, this code does not work:

```
const result = { let a = 1 + 2; a };
```

I get this error:

```
const result = { let a = 1 + 2; a };
                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

What am I missing here? Am I correct in assuming that the block evaluates to the last expression within it, or is Node's REPL misleading me here?

Comment: If you *start* with `{` it's a block, if you have `varName = {` it's an object literal.

Comment: you treat a block statement as object. this does not work.

Comment: Why does Node say that the block evaluates to something? How can I make use of what the block evaluates to if I have to throw it away?

Comment: A block is irrelevant. You can never get a value out of the block itself - there is no way to have a *code block* in expression context. What the REPL logs is for convenience - it seems to choose the last statement. This isn't dissimilar to variable declarations which also don't produce any value - they are *statements*, so they are also invalid in expression contexts. Yet the console will log `undefined` to at least acknowledge the code was processed.

Comment: @Flimm One can use `eval` to get the last completion value of a block (or any other statement). That's also how the console does it. You *should* however never use this.

Comment: @Flimm it still states that you cannot get a value from a block. A REPL evaluating your code and *your code* evaluating the code are different. That's always been the case. Your original issue was that you wanted to somehow evaluate a block as code and get a value out of it. That's still not possible. `eval()` is at best a hack around it but not really how you're supposed to solve this, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've seen in the Node REPL, a block evaluates to a value, and that value is usually the value of the last statement in the block.

In [ECMAScript 6.0](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-block), a `BlockStatement` is defined as follows (with subscripts omitted for simplicity):

```
BlockStatement:
    Block

Block:
    { StatementList }

StatementList:
    StatementListItem
    StatementList StatementListItem

StatementListItem:
    Statement
    Declaration
```

Per [section 13.2.13](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-block-runtime-semantics-evaluation), Note 2, "The value of a `StatementList` is the value of the last value producing item in the `StatementList`." A `Block` is evaluated to the value of its `StatementList`, and a `BlockStatement` is evaluated to the value of its `Block`.

Thus, Node is correctly evaluating your `BlockStatement` to the value of the last value producing item, which is `a`. This is not a bug, nor is it specific to Node.

The reason you are getting an error is because you are trying to use a `BlockStatement` in a context where it is not allowed.

`const result = { let a = 1 + 2; a };` is a `LexicalDeclaration`, which [is defined](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations) as follows (again, with subscripts omitted):

```
LexicalDeclaration:
    LetOrConst BindingList ;

LetOrConst :
    let
    const

BindingList:
    LexicalBinding
    BindingList , LexicalBinding

LexicalBinding:
    BindingIdentifier Initializer
    BindingPattern Initializer
```

We also need the [definition](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-object-initializer) of `Initializer`:

```
Initializer:
    = AssignmentExpression
```

As you can see, the part of your lexical declaration after the equal sign requires an `AssignmentExpression`. If you look through the [grammar](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-expressions) for expressions, you will see that `BlockStatement` is not an `AssignmentExpression`.

As of ES6.0, there is no way to use a `BlockStatement` direcly as an `AssignmentExpression`. However, if you want to evaluate one to an expression, you can use `eval`:

```
> const result = eval("{ let a = 1 + 2; a }");
> result
3
```

I don't recommend doing this under ordinary circumstances, but it is helpful for seeing how ES6.0 does indeed evaluate blocks to values.

Answer (score -2):

In js braces represent an object which expects `key: value` pairs. You can get the result like this;

```js
const result = {a: 1 + 2};
console.log(result.a);
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is wrong in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't downvote. My question was about how to get the result of evaluating a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), which is also represented by braces. I'm not asking about object literals.

Comment: @Irfanwani braces aren't always an object, they also represent blocks